# How to get access to any DOM element from any view in Ember Js framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, ember.js

I have an ember js application with nested views. And I can't get access to the elements in parent views by `Ember.$(selector)` to do some manipulations.

There is one way to get access by putting `Ember.$(selector)` inside `Ember.run.next(function(){...})` function but it's too tricky and I think it's not correct and proper way.

Is there a good way to get access to the parent DOM elements inside parent view but outside this current view, or I should refactor my code when I meet situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably send an action to the parent and let it manipulate it's own view using the template.

Comment: I didn't catch your idea. Can you provide an example or link to documentation?